# RobotFrameWork: how can I use a function in a function?

Tags: robotframework

So there's a nice keyword in RFW which is:

Table Cell Should Contain,

But now It should check the tabletext against a regexp. but it doesn't seem to work that way, because it says,
*text not found*

```
*** Variables
${pattern2}       ^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}

 Table Cell Should Contain    xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    2    6   ${pattern2}
```

this doesn't work: either i guess:

```
Table Cell Should Contain    xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    2    6   regexp:^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

Comment: The keyword does not work with regexp - it looks for a substring in the cell's value. Get the text, and use it in `Should Match Regexp` like in your previous question.

Comment: yes like so:  Should Match Regexp  xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table  ^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}

Comment: But how do i point to the exact row and column then?

Comment: my actual question is I think: How can I use a Keyword in a codeline of a keyword

Comment: like so:     Table Cell Should contain.. bla bla bla bla... Should Match Rexexp bla

Comment: I think there's some mix-up; `Table Cell Should Contain` expects you provide the actual text (not regexp) that should be in that cell. For instance, if the cell value is "bla bla bla", you would call `Table Cell Should Contain   table_locator    1    2  bla bla". `Should Match Regexp` expects two strings - the string you will search in - not a locator, but a string/text, and the regexp to test it with.

Comment: yes i know. so how to check a table cell that matches a regexp!!

Comment: > so how to check a table cell that matches a regexp!!   - Get the text - `${the text}=  
  Get Text    locator`, and use it in Should Match Regexp - `Should Match Regexp   ${the text} ${pattern2}`

Comment: a few things Todor,
1) where to place ${thetext}? at variables?
2) it doesnt work if I type this the locator stays blue text (doesn't become a locator)
3) how can I locate to  " xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    2    5 " (the class name and id changes)

Answer (score 2):

Regretfully, no, in Robot Framework you cannot chain keywords - to use the output of one directly as an input for another. You have to have intermediate/temp variables for that.

For the case here, you want to see does a table cell has text, matching a specific regular expression. As the keyword `Table Cell Should Contain` does not support regexp in the looked-for argument, but only normal strings, you can't use it.
Break down this verification in 2 steps - first get the text in the cell (in a temp variable), and then see does it match the regular expression with the `Should Match Regexp` keyword:

```
*** Variables ***
${pattern2}       ^[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}

*** Testcases ***
A case
    ${temp variable}=    Get Text     xpath=locator_that_will_return_the_specific_cell
    # alternatively, you can use this keyword - if the table is an actual <table> element in the html
    # ${temp variable}=    Get Text     xpath=locator_that_will_return_the_table   2    5
    # now having the text in the cell, see does it match the regexp
    Should Match Regexp    ${temp variable}    ${pattern2}
```

As to what are the values of "locator_that_will_return_the_specific_cell" and "locator_that_will_return_the_table" - I can't tell you; nor anyone else, without a sample of the HTML.

Comment: Also I'd like RFW to show at which line of the .robot file it is testing. more info on the current run in the Eclipse would be very appreciated.

Comment: this was fault: ${the text}=   (the = sign) and that's why it didn't work (watch the details please haha! ;)

Comment: Table Cell Should Contain has a possibility to  give in  a row and a colum....
like so: xpath=//div[@id='components_block']/table    2    5
so that was the thing that made my head spin

Comment: This was the specific URL by the way: https://www.investing.com/equities/pre-market

Comment: The equal sign (`=`) is not an error - it is optional in RF, it can be present or omitted just after a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found I direct match/hit to the table location like so:  xptah=//tr[1]/td[4]

then I could do this:

```
 ${gettext}   Get Text  xpath=//tr[1]/td[4]
    Should Match Regexp  ${gettext}  ^[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}
```